# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{\sin n}{5n + 1}\right)^{2n + 3}$ (a $1^\infty$ indeterminate form)

Tags: limits, analysis, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

My professor gave us this limit as part of homework:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{\sin n}{5n + 1}\right)^{2n + 3}
$$
I can see it's in the indeterminate form $1^{\infty}$, so my first thought was to write it in the form $\lim_{n\to0}\left(1 + n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ since I know that's equal to $e$, so I tried that:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{\sin n}{5n + 1}\right)^{2n + 3} &= \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{\sin n}{5n + 1}\right)^{\left(2n+3\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\frac{\sin n}{5n + 1}}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\sin n}{5n + 1}\right)} &= \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1 + \frac{\sin n}{5n + 1}\right)^{\frac{1}{\frac{\sin n}{5n + 1}}}\right)^{\frac{2n + 3}{5n + 1}\cdot\sin n} &=
\end{align*}
$$

Up to this point I was happy, 'cause I successfully wrote it in that form, but I got stuck when I tried to solve the limit of the outermost exponent, since it doesn't have a limit.
I apologize in advance for any grammatical or sentence structure errors, English is not my first language. Anyways, any feedback about this problem, like hints, where my error was, or literally anything, is extremely accepted!

Comment: I don't think it converges. When $n=(4k+1)\pi/2$ it converges to $e^{2/5}$, and when $n = (4k+3)\pi/2$ it converges to $e^{-2/5}$.

Comment: You will need to use that you can find strictly increasing sequences of natural numbers $n_k$ and $m_k$ such that $\sin(n_k)\to1$ and $\sin(m_k)\to -1$, by using rational approximations of $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$.

Comment: Intuitively, this seems asymptotic to $(e^{(\sin n)/5})^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Using $1 + rx < (1 + x)^r < \exp(rx)$, we have
$$
1 + \frac{2n+3}{5n+1}\sin n < \left(1 + \frac{\sin n}{5n+1}\right)^{2n + 3} <  \exp\left(\frac{2n+3}{5n+1}\sin n\right).
$$
For any $n$ such that $\sin n > 1/2$ (and there are infinitely many), we have
$$
1 + \frac{2n+3}{5n+1}\sin n > 1 + \frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = 1.2.
$$
For any $n$ such that $\sin n < -1/2$ (also infinitely many), we have
$$
\exp\left(\frac{2n+3}{5n+1}\sin n\right) < \exp\left(-\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right) < 0.9.
$$
And thus the limit can't exist, as the value is infinitely often less than $0.9$ and infinitely often greater than $1.2$.

Answer (score 0):

Define

$$L:=\left( 1+\frac{\sin n}{5n+1} \right)^{2n+3},$$

and take the logarithm of both sides to bring the exponent down. Proceed from there.

Comment: We technically haven't been taught that, so sadly I can't use it

Comment: Oh. This is the standard technique. Now I'm just curious how you were taught to handle the indeterminate forms $1^\infty$?

Comment: So far, our professor only taught us to write it in the form of the limit representation of $e$. I wish I could use other methods, like this one, but I've had problems with my math professors for not using their method, so I try to stick, at least for homework, to what they said :)

Comment: @DiegoRodríguez Yes, what you are being taught is is **a** correct technique. "Taking logarithms" not only is not "the standard technique" (there is no such thing as the standard technique), but it is also an erroneous deduction process or at best unjustified. You cannot take logarithm until you know if the limit exists. The correct version of "taking logarithms" is to replace your expression of the form $a^b$ by the expression $e^{\ln(a^b)}=e^{b\ln(a)}$. For this you also need to check that $a>0$ or $\neq 0$.

Comment: @plop It's called $\textit{formally}$ taking logarithms. One reasons as if everything is justified, and abandons the approach if it's later discovered that it isn't. No one proves limits exist in calculus, which is where these appear. This is the standard approach for $1^\infty$. There are standard techniques for virtually every type of problem in math. This is statement is a truism. How is writing $e^{\ln(a^b)}$ really any different?

Comment: Taking logarithms should be  a rather trivial thing for anyone studying calculus, in my opinion. Now, using that the logarithm is a continuous function, which you'd need to deduce the limit in case it exists,  could be a little more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Take logarithm and write it as

$$\frac 25((5n+1+\frac{13}{2})\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{\sin(n)}{5n+1}\Bigr)$$
the limit becomes
$$=\frac 25\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{\sin(n)}{5n+1}\Bigr)}{\frac{\sin(n)}{5n+1}}\sin(n)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sin(n)$$
which does not exist.

Observe that

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{13}{5}\ln(1+\frac{\sin(n)}{5n+1})=0$$

So, your limit does not exist.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but, as I said in @innerproduct 's reply, we haven't been taught that method yet. In any case, I have to thank both of you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{\sin n}{5n + 1}\right)^{2n + 3} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left[\color{red}{\left(1 + \frac{\sin n}{5n + 1}\right)^{\frac{5n+1}{\sin n}}}\right]^{\color{green}{\frac{2n+3}{5n+1}}}\right]^{\sin n}$$
The limit of red part is $e$, green part is $\frac25$ and black part doesn't exist. So the overall limit oscillates between $e^{\frac25}$ and $e^{-\frac25}$ and doesn't exist.